# pipenv install glob fails

Tags: package, installation, glob, pipenv

I tried to install glob in my virtual python (version 3.5) environment.  This is an error I got.  I found similar questions on this channel, but not much of help.

$pipenv install glob
Installing glob…
Collecting glob

Error:  An error occurred while installing glob!
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement glob (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for glob

Comment: glob is part of the Standard Library in Python so you do not need to install it.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that pipenv looks up the version in the url specified in [[source]] in the Pipfile and glob is not in there. However, glob is part of the [Standard Library in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) so you do not need to install it via pipenv and you can just call it from your script 'import glob' and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are using python 3.X
here are the correct glob versions

## for python 2.7

```
sudo pip install glob2
```

## for python 3.7

```
sudo pip3 install glob3
```

Comment: `python 3.7` doesn't work....the right command is `sudo pip3 install glob2`